# RAM requirements for a 100GB RAM drive

Tags: memory, ramdisk

Let's say I want to have a 100GB ram drive for gaming.
Is the only way of getting that is to have greater than 100GB of RAM?

For X GB of RAM Disk is it required to have more than X GB of RAM?

Software like [DIMMDrive](http://dimmdrive.com/) claims to work on even 256MB of RAM? Is it a special case of DIMMDrive, or other free RAM Drives have the same features?

Comment: I'm not really sure why all the downvotes - We weren't all born with the ability to read between the lines on a "technical" aspect - if you read the advert, they almost make out that **anyone** can have a 256GB RAM disk... lots of snake oil going on, even if the underlying app is sound, I think they're trying to sell it to a lot of people who don't realise it won't give them the real benefits they are after.

Comment: -1 for sloppy questions.  (a) *"For X GB of RAM ... than X GB of RAM?'*  -- RAM versus RAM comparison.  (b) *"Software like DIMMDrive claims to work on even 256MB of RAM?"* -- There's no such claim in their ad.

Comment: @sawdust - a) is quickly fixed. b) quote... "While other programs restrict the complete use of RAM to their own brand modules, DimmDrive can allocate the maximum quantity recognized for your OS, up to 256GB in Windows 8 Enterprise and Professional."

Comment: @Tetsujin -- The OP wrote *"256MB"*, and your quote has *"256GB"*.

Comment: Yes..., again quote "DimmDrive can use any amount of RAM, from 256MB to 256GB." I'm not defending here, I really have little to gain. I just think the OP's being punished for not already knowing the answer to the question he asked.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- If it's not sloppy writing, and the OP actually found that bogus claim of 64-bit Windows needing only 256MB, then he ***ignored*** the answer he was looking for in the previous sentence: *"...with at least more RAM than your OS+programs use"*

Comment: I still think he's being punished for not being able to decipher snake oil advertising. Anyway, that's my last word on the subject; the Q already has 6 down-votes & 2 close-votes. I'm sure nothing I say will change that.

Comment: I'm with Tetsujin on this. A couple simple questions that experience should have made clear would have enabled OP to learn while improving their question. "Did you mean 256GB?" and "Are you asking if there is certain amount of RAM in a RAM drive lost to overhead?" and "How much RAM were you hoping to have available as memory for the OS?" all would have helped OP much more than the drive-by downvotes. This place isn't SF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their ad kind of hides it from you, making you think you can have up to 256GB...

But to use 256GB you need to **have** 256GB spare!

You can only make a RAM disk as big as your actual RAM, less what you need to run the OS normally.

Theoretically, you may be able allocate more RAM to a RAM disk than you own, but you would be completely defeating the object as your OS would then be paging the excess back to your regular HD/SSD, making the entire process slower than before you set up the RAM disk.

From their [web page](http://dimmdrive.com)... hidden away down the bottom...

> **What are the requirements to run DimmDrive?**
>
> A 64bit PC running Windows 7 or above, with any CPU, with at least
> more RAM than your OS+programs use. DimmDrive can use any amount of
> RAM, from 256MB to 256GB.
>
> **How much RAM do I need for DimmDrive?**
>
> The more RAM you have, the better. It really boils down to what you are using it for. Also,
> DimmDrive has a feature we call “Less RAM?” which enables you to
> selectively pick which files in a game you want to go blazing fast.
> This feature alone can take a 10GB game and slim it down to 4GB-ish by
> removing video/intro files, sound files, and other non-essential files
> that do not need to go blazing fast. If you are doing light gaming, we
> recommend having 6GB+ RAM. If you are doing heavy gaming, we recommend
> 8-16GB. If you are using DimmDrive for things like Audio/Visual
> scratch disk, you typically will want 2GB or more for that. As with
> everything PC related, the more RAM, the better!

A RAM disk isn't "magic", though the ad makes it sound like it is. It's a good way of quickly being able to load resources already saved to it, as they state.
For any RAM disk, you set it up, then copy data to it. If the RAM disk is put away without saving its contents back to HD, then everything is lost.
As far as I can see, their 'special ingredient/selling point' is just that they are periodically saving back to HD in case of power-loss, so that no data is lost.
They also appear to have some kind of data slimming system, presumably they're doing something like aliases/hard/soft links back to the larger files to make it appear to the game that they are all in the right place.

I use RAM disks all the time on Mac, copying out & back in a similar way as they describe - but I have 64GB RAM to play with, so size isn't an issue. I don't actually have any fail-safe on mine, but I'm using ephemeral data which would not be a disaster if I lost a few hours' work.

Unfortunately, I have no ides how you would write that for Windows, sorry.

Comment: So to have a 100GB RAM Disk you would need 100GB of RAM right ?

Comment: Call it 108 or better 116, so you've at least a bit spare to still work with.

Comment: @Tetsujin Technically in order to get a 256GB RAM drive you would need more than 256GB of memory.

Comment: @Ramhound - Yup, thought I'd said that - "You can only make a RAM disk as big as your actual RAM, less what you need to run the OS normally." I was really exaggerating the need to have that colossal amount of RAM to stat with, which I'm pretty sure not a lot of people do ;) I'll add the necessary extra word...

Comment: You did but I must have interpreted a sentence incorrectly.

Comment: @Ramhound - I clarified, with another quote from DIMMDrive